# algorithm for lowest chromatic number of a undirected graph

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

I'm searching for a graph coloring algorithm that will always give the best solution to an undirected and simple graph, i have searched the greedy algorithms (welsh-Powell) and they give a best solution for multiple graphs, but not always.

should i use backtracking algorithms ?

does this problem have a solution with polynomial time complexity ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_coloring#Computational_complexity

Comment: If your graph can have any general structure, then finding an optimal colouring is NP-hard so it is highly unlikely that a polytime algorithm exists for it (so backtracking is a fine approach). If your graph has any sort of specialized structure, it is possible that efficient algorithms exist, depending on what that structure is